# How to make image-map pop-up

Tags: javascript, html, popup

Hello i'm using PHPDevel Popup Window `(http://www.php-development.ru/javascripts/popup-window.php)`

And i'm trying to integrate my popup in my image-map And it's not working..

my image map:

```
<img src="http://i34.tinypic.com/4tlkci.jpg" usemap="#Map" border="0">
    <map name="Map" id="Map">
      <area shape="circle" coords="120,109,67" href="#" />
    </map>
```

And my popup:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://kgv-projekt.hr/pop/popup-window.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://kgv-projekt.hr/pop/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://kgv-projekt.hr/pop/popup-window.js"></script>
```

Body:

```
<!-- Anchor start -->
<a href="#" onclick="popup_window_show('#popup_window_id_2B7668D9714CE2A0158E3F1DA9DD0BA3', { pos : 'window-center', parent : this, x : 0, y : 0, width : 'auto' }); return false;">Open popup window</a>
<!-- Anchor end -->

<!-- Popup Window start -->
<div id="popup_window_id_2B7668D9714CE2A0158E3F1DA9DD0BA3" class="popup_window_css"><table class="popup_window_css"><tr><td class="popup_window_css"><div class="popup_window_css_head"><img src="http://kgv-projekt.hr/pop/images/close.gif" alt="" width="9" height="9" />Stock</div><div class="popup_window_css_body"><fieldset style=" margin-bottom:25px; float:left;">
<legend style=" width:170px; text-align: center;">Something </legend>
  <table width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td height="59"><p>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="a7" value="1">
          1. One</label>
          <br>
          <br>

      </p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="59"><select name="aa7" id="aa7"><option>Submit</option></select></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</fieldset></div><div class="popup_window_css_foot"><a href="http://www.php-development.ru/javascripts/popup-window.php" title="Powered by PHPDevel Popup Window | PHPDevel web scripts collection"><img src="http://kgv-projekt.hr/pop/images/about.gif" alt="" width="6" height="6" /></a></div></td></tr></table></div>
<!-- Popup Window end -->
```

Any suggestions? or how can i do that with `Window open()` Method?

Comment: I didn't get what you want to do. Can you show your hole html-page?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/A9TTR/ This is fiddle of imagemap.. and i want when you click on puppys head that popup opens with code that i provide up

Answer (score 0):

```
<body style="text-align: center">
<img src="image.jpg" alt="" width="1513" height="983" usemap="#Map"/>
<map name="Map">
  <area shape="poly"coords="149,297,121,399,248,598,221,652,151,643,134,599,77,545,28,375,26,323,47,268,148,297"     href="popup.html" target="_blank" onclick="javascript:void               window.open('http://www.sethharden.com/sis/california.html','1407798238173','width=650,height=    800,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=0,top=0');return     false;">
</map>
```

Comment: I'm sure the OP would appreciate some words of explanation besides the code example.